# Is there a venue or basic protocol that could allow people to collaborate on writing and improving tag wiki proposed edits?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Should be self explanatory.  There are various subjects on SO with no or effectively no real tag wiki, and some of these subjects really need some clarifications and guidelines about asking relevant questions.

Is there a venue, protocol, even any interest in such for that matter where people could get together and work out and refine some really good wikis for submission to those who have rep to approve?

Comment: IMO, chat at least partially fits the bill.  Text changes can be posted and starred, though it's not ideal for storing any full documents.

Comment: +1. I did quite some tag wiki edits two days ago, and in some cases I think it would have been better to discuss them with someone. Similar, when I'm asked to approve the edits.

Comment: @jonsca: I never had the idea to use chat for this. There should be at least some indication in the tag info page that such a discussion is ongoing. (Or maybe in general a link to the right chat room?)

Comment: @Paŭlo I don't think there's explicitly a room for this type of thing, but users over 100 rep on the respective site can create their own chat room.  You could then leave some indication that interested parties can go to the room to discuss it.

Comment: @jonsca: The question is, would we want to discuss this in a general *stack overflow tag wiki* chat room, or some chat room related to the tag? Or a special chat room for each tag wiki (or even for each edit)?

Comment: @Paŭlo You could discuss it in a room called  Paŭlo's Pub and Grille if you wanted. :)  Chat rooms can always be closed or reorganized, and a lot of it would depend on the community that arose around the tag edits.  Even if you made a "All Tag Edits Here" room, someone still has the right to start their own.

Comment: Of course, the question is not what is allowed, but what would be useful here :-)

Comment: @Paŭlo I agree.  Honestly, I'm not sure there's any right answer.  You'd need input from whomever it is you'd be working with, but you can't know who that will be unless you have a venue in which to meet.  I'd say start something, let it evolve within reason, and see where it goes.

Comment: thanks for the comments, sorry for such a late response i had to take a temporary hiatus from SO and my tag edit ideas have similarly gotten nowhere so far.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit review process *is* the protocol.

If you look at the top 50 or so tags on any given site, you should get a pretty good feel for how a tag should be written.  As Wikipedia says, "Be bold."  Submit your tag wikis, using your best judgement on how that tag wiki should look.

I would be cautious, though, about putting detailed prose into a tag wiki *describing how the tag should be used.*  You should get consensus on such detailed instructions, either by using chat or posting a question here.

If possible, such instructions should be put into the *tag wiki body,* not the tag wiki excerpt; the excerpt, while more visible and prominent, really doesn't work well for this, for a number of reasons: it's too short, and it gets truncated when displayed if it is too long.